# How to make a POST to get an access token for a JSON petition in C#?

Tags: c#, json, post, token

I'm trying to generate a token so I can get access to a server that returns a JSON file. I have read the documentation of the API of the server and it says something like this:

**Verb** ->POST

**Protocol** -> http://

**Primary_domain** -> api.actitudfem.com

**Action** -> register

**Datatype** -> json

**Required_parameters** -> appid=[unique_id]

**Optional_parameters** ->&name=[username]&email=[useremail]

**Url** ->http://api.actitudfem.com/register.json

Could anyone please help me by showing me how to get the token so I can use it to download the JSON file?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a HttpWebRequest.

Make sure you reference these:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
```

Then use the following:

```
    const string url = "http://api.actitudfem.com/register.json";

    string postData = "appid=SomeUniqueID";
    var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";

    using (var postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);

    string json = String.Empty;
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            json = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Then you can choose to append `&name=[username]&email=[useremail]` to the postData if required.

Comment: @OmarOsorio Np. Mark the question as answered if you are happy.